# ViGEm.NET namespace missing when using Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gamepad-api

[this question has the unity3d tag and I can't change it to unity2d]
I was trying to use ViGEm using [this](https://forums.vigem.org/topic/273/vigem-net-feeder-example-step-by-step) tutorial to help me.
But when I was writing the code, a red underline appeared on `using Nefarius.ViGEm.Client;`
It said: `The type or namespace 'Nefarius' could not be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How do I make this work with Unity? I have carefully done every step of the tutorial.

Comment: Try [Nugget for Unity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) and install that `Nefarius` thing into your project .. however: Make sure it supports your target platform

Comment: It didn't work, but I made it work with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps fixed it:

1. Go to the nuget website and download the package.
2. Extract the file as a .zip file.
3. Go inside the `lib` folder and copy the .dll file to [Unity Project]\Assets\Plugins (create the folder if it doesn't exist)